# Lower / upper load factor in hash tables

Tags: java, hashtable, load-factor

I am to write a chained hash set class in java.

I understand the load factor is M/capacity where M is the number of elements currently in the table and capacity is the size of the table.

But how does the load factor help me determine if I should resize the table and rehash or not?
Also I couldn't find anywhere how to calculate the lower / upper load factors. Are they even needed?

I hope this is enough information,
Thank you!!

Comment: A question is unclear. JDK `HashMap` does rehash at loadFactor = 0.75.

Comment: I'm attempting to build my own hash set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `loadFactor` used to configure standard Java hashes (and in a number of hash APIs in other languages) is a simplification.

Conceptually, it is reasonable to distingush

- *Target load*, indicate a default memory footprint -- performance tradeoff configuration. when you build a hash of the known size, you choose capacity so that size/capacity is as close to target load, as possible.
- *Max load*, you want a hash to never exceed this load. You trigger a resize, if a hash reach this load.
- *Grow factor*, a default configuration of how much to enlarge a hash on resize. If capacity is a power of 2, grow factor could be only either 2 or 4.
- *Min load*, you want a hash load to never be lower than the min load, maybe unless you remove elements or clear a hash. If capacity is a power of 2, min load couldn't be greater than 0.5. Additionally, max load / min load ratio should be greater or equal to grow factor.

All the above concerns chained hash, for open addressing hash with tombstones things are getting even more complicated.

In `java.util.HashMap` `loadFactor` plays the roles of target and max load simultaneously. Grow factor is 2, min load is 0.0.

For chained hash non-power-of-2 capacity is overkill unless you need *extremely* precise control over memory usage (you don't, trust me) or a capacity between 2^30 and 2^31-1 (because you can't create an array of size 2^31 in Java, it is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` + 1).

Answer (score 0):

It works the other way around: it's not that the load factor helps you; you **explicitely** decide the load factor based on your performance tests, to avoid wasting time rehashing and still have the acceptable retrieval and iteration performance.

Comment: So I decide the load factor. If m/capacity is lower or if it's higher, I rehash but change the table size accordingly? And also does the table size need to be prime?

Comment: @k20 The table size can be anything you want, but usually a multiple of 2 is picked to speed up the calculation of the bucket index