# Can we implement cuckoo hashing using 1 table?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I found about [Cuckoo Hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing) and they seem pretty good.
But most examples code I found implement this using 2 tables.
This seems to me wrong because the 2 tables may be in different memory pages and we have overhead of fetching random addresses and have no real locality.
Is it not possible to use 1 array instead of 2?
Is it perhaps not possible to detect when an element has already been kicked out 2 times and is time for resizing?

Comment: you can allocate the two tables in the same block of memory, i.e. one allocation, to ensure spacial locality

Comment: Trivially yes, allocate one table then just chop it into two pieces.

Comment: also note that L1 cache is in the order of several KBs on todays systems (lookup current intel micro architectures for example) and thus have space for several pages of memory - having to index into a small number of pages should not be a problem either

Comment: @BeyelerStudios:Is this a language specific issue?E.g. in Java which I am interested in you can not do this

Comment: @harold:I was thinking it might not be possible to detect that it is the second eviction of an element if using 1 table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the confusion in the comments: no this is not language specific. If you're thinking about memory locality and want to ensure the two tables are close, then a single allocation is the way to go (however you allocate). In java this may look as follows:

```java
class TwoTables {
    private static final int SIZE_TABLE_FIRST = 11, SIZE_TABLE_SECOND = 29;

    public TwoTables() {
        m_buffer = new int[SIZE_TABLE_FIRST + SIZE_TABLE_SECOND];
    }

    // consider similar setters...

    public int getFirst(int key) {
        return m_buffer[toIndex(hashFirst(key), SIZE_TABLE_FIRST, 0)];
    }

    public int getSecond(int key) {
        return m_buffer[toIndex(hashSecond(key), SIZE_TABLE_SECOND, SIZE_TABLE_FIRST)];
    }

    private static int toIndex(int hash, int mod, int offset) {
        return hash % mod + offset;
    }

    private static int hashFirst(int key) { return ...; }
    private static int hashSecond(int key) { return ...; }

    private final int[] m_buffer;
}
```

If this performs better than accessing into two separate arrays is dependant on your JVM however: just think about the JIT being able to merge two small allocations into a single larger one on the fly - without you having to perform any index-magic.

Comment: But why would the index calculation be more of an overhead than accessing another array in another memory page?

Comment: @Jim as with many other performance questions: you will have to measure it on your system. Especially comparing indexing and accessing over page boundaries, with a virtual machine, the specifics of how the JIT is producing instructions will make all the difference - not your idea of how those instructions should be generated.

Comment: But what does `you will have to measure it on your system` mean? Which system? What kind of system should be used for such a testing of a generic data structure?

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do a cuckoo hashtable with a single hash table; that is, where the two positions for each object are simply positions within a single hash table.

The only small problem to be solved is how to decide during the cuckoo eviction loop which of the two positions to use for an evicted key. Of course, you can just try one position and use the other one if the first one was the same as the actual position. It should be possible to use SIMD to compute both hashes in parallel, so the cost of this strategy might be small.

However, if you want to guarantee a single hash computation during the cuckoo loop, there is a simple solution: instead of using `H0(k)` and `H1(k)` as the two positions, use `H0(k)` and `H0(k) xor H1(k)`. (If `H1` is independent from `H0`, then so is `H0 xor H1`, so the xor does not affect the distribution of hash values.) With this modification, you can always find "the other position" of `k` by xor'ing the current position with `H1(k)`, so only a single hash computation is needed in the loop.

While that allows you to use a single hash table, and may even simplify the code, there is not a lot of evidence that it improves the operation of the algorithm. In my limited testing, it seems to increase the number of loop iterations by 40-50%. (Although it needs to be emphasized that in the vast majority of cases, a new key can be inserted into the table without entering the loop at all, so the increased number of loops is hardly noticeable in the actual execution time.)

Comment: Apologies for the late answer. I stumbled upon this question while researching cuckoo hashing, and this answer seemed relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all forms of hashing are murder on caches.

Anyways you can easily combine the two into a single table.  But then how do you tell whether you're on your first hash function or the second?  The options are add that as metadata to every bucket, or else figure it out by running the first hash function, seeing whether you got the current location, and running the second only if you were on the first.  That either requires extra space, or running more hash functions.

Splitting the table into 2 solves that problem more efficiently.  And statistically you need the same number of buckets to store the same number of things whether or not the table has been split.  So your whole hash table becomes smaller.

Comment: Is there a chance that the 2 hash functions collide for some element and size of the array and so actually not using 2 tables is inevitable?

Comment: `all forms of hashing are murder on caches.` As far as I have read open addressing does not have this problem that you mention

Comment: @Jim On an insert there is always a chance that insertion will create a cycle and you have to rebuild the table with two new hash functions.  That is true whether you use one table or two.

As for hashes killing caches, I said all and I meant all.  The first step is compute a hash function and jump to a pseudo random place in a block of memory.  If that block is bigger than cache, you're likely to be blowing your cache.

Concrete example.  In many use cases a BTree with more data than fits in RAM averages significantly under one disk seek per lookup.  A hash of the same size always seeks.

Comment: @btilly I can argue with this statement `all forms of hashing are murder on caches`. 1) According to Pareto principle likely, a small subset of entries, that makes major part of accesses, hot and sit in closest caches. 2) That said, anything except scanning continous block of memory is "cache murder", not constructive 3) making one random access and making two of them is a big difference. That makes linear hashing much more efficient, than double hashing, for example.

Comment: @leventov In turn.  1) Yes, there will be hot pages.  But generally you'll have a page with 1 key/value pair that is hot, and the rest of it is dragged into cache to evict something else.  Over and over again.  This is not how caches like to be treated.  2) Surprisingly complex access patterns can work well with caches.  I offered a BTree.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm for more examples.  3) The fact that you could do worse does not mean that you are doing well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

http://www.spoj.com/problems/CUCKOO/

You can check this problem on spoj,we need to do this problem using a single hash table and two hash functions.